# qemu kvm vm can't access network with ovs dpdk

Tags: qemu, dpdk, openvswitch

i'm using ovs with dpdk to improve network performance, but i can't resolve the problem by my self

### DPDK dev bind script output

```
# dpdk-devbind.py -s

Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:07:00.0 'I350 Gigabit Network Connection 1521' drv=igb_uio unused=igb,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic
0000:07:00.1 'I350 Gigabit Network Connection 1521' drv=igb_uio unused=igb,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:01:00.0 'Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 1528' if=eno1 drv=ixgbe unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic *Active*
0000:01:00.1 'Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 1528' if=eno2 drv=ixgbe unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic

No 'Baseband' devices detected
==============================

No 'Crypto' devices detected
============================

No 'Eventdev' devices detected
==============================

No 'Mempool' devices detected
=============================

No 'Compress' devices detected
==============================

No 'Misc (rawdev)' devices detected
===================================
```

### ovs config

```
# ovs-vsctl --no-wait get Open_vSwitch . other_config
{dpdk-init="true", dpdk-lcore-mask="0x6", pmd-cpu-mask="0x24"}
```

### cpu info

```
# lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          24
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-23
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              6
Socket(s):                       2
NUMA node(s):                    2
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           62
Model name:                      Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz
Stepping:                        4
CPU MHz:                         2965.447
CPU max MHz:                     3100.0000
CPU min MHz:                     1200.0000
BogoMIPS:                        5199.97
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       384 KiB
L1i cache:                       384 KiB
L2 cache:                        3 MiB
L3 cache:                        30 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22
NUMA node1 CPU(s):               1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: Split huge pages
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx es
                                 t tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
```

### hugepage info

```
# grep Huge /proc/meminfo
AnonHugePages:   1214464 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:    8192
HugePages_Free:     5846
HugePages_Rsvd:     1488
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:        16777216 kB
```

### vm startup script

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-enable-kvm \
-cpu host,kvm=off \
-smp 4 \
-m 8192M \
-object memory-backend-file,id=mem,size=1G,mem-path=/dev/hugepages,share=on \
-mem-prealloc \
-chardev socket,id=char-vm-2004-tpl,path=/var/run/openvswitch-vhost/vhost-vm-2004-tpl,server \
-netdev type=vhost-user,id=net-vm-2004-tpl,chardev=char-vm-2004-tpl,vhostforce \
-device virtio-net-pci,mac=52:54:14:cb:ab:6c,netdev=net-vm-2004-tpl \
-drive file=/opt/image/ubuntu-2004-tpl.img,if=virtio \
-vga qxl \
-spice port=15937,disable-ticketing \
-qmp tcp:0.0.0.0:25937,server,nowait \
-daemonize
```

### ovs status

```
# ovs-vsctl show
2a4487e3-124a-4b66-92e1-1e824fd9a138
    Bridge br0
        datapath_type: netdev
        Port vhost-vm-2004-tpl
            Interface vhost-vm-2004-tpl
                type: dpdkvhostuserclient
                options: {vhost-server-path="/var/run/openvswitch-vhost/vhost-vm-2004-tpl"}
        Port dpdk-p0
            Interface dpdk-p0
                type: dpdk
                options: {dpdk-devargs="0000:07:00.0"}
        Port br0
            Interface br0
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "2.14.90"
```

### ovs OpenFlow status

```
# ovs-ofctl show br0
OFPT_FEATURES_REPLY (xid=0x2): dpid:0000ecf4bbe2f494
n_tables:254, n_buffers:0
capabilities: FLOW_STATS TABLE_STATS PORT_STATS QUEUE_STATS ARP_MATCH_IP
actions: output enqueue set_vlan_vid set_vlan_pcp strip_vlan mod_dl_src mod_dl_dst mod_nw_src mod_nw_dst mod_nw_tos mod_tp_src mod_tp_dst
 1(dpdk-p0): addr:ec:f4:bb:e2:f4:94
     config:     0
     state:      0
     current:    1GB-FD AUTO_NEG
     speed: 1000 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 2(vhost-vm-2004-t): addr:00:00:00:00:00:00
     config:     0
     state:      LINK_DOWN
     speed: 0 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 LOCAL(br0): addr:ec:f4:bb:e2:f4:94
     config:     0
     state:      0
     current:    10MB-FD COPPER
     speed: 10 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
OFPT_GET_CONFIG_REPLY (xid=0x4): frags=normal miss_send_len=0
```

the vm can't get ip address by dhcp, and when i run command " ip link set ens3 up " on the vm,
it tell me "RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted"

the kernel version of host is
5.4.0-52-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

the kernel version of vm is
5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 19:50:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

DPDK version:
DPDK 19.11.5

open vSwitch version:
2.14.90 (commit id:93023e80bd13ec1f09831eba484cf4621582d1a5 of https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs branch master)

### ovs full log

```
2020-10-27T17:46:36.950Z|00001|vlog|INFO|opened log file /usr/local/var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log
2020-10-27T17:46:36.982Z|00002|ovs_numa|INFO|Discovered 12 CPU cores on NUMA node 1
2020-10-27T17:46:36.982Z|00003|ovs_numa|INFO|Discovered 12 CPU cores on NUMA node 0
2020-10-27T17:46:36.982Z|00004|ovs_numa|INFO|Discovered 2 NUMA nodes and 24 CPU cores
2020-10-27T17:46:36.983Z|00005|reconnect|INFO|unix:/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: connecting...
2020-10-27T17:46:36.983Z|00006|reconnect|INFO|unix:/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: connected
2020-10-27T17:46:36.985Z|00007|dpdk|INFO|Using DPDK 19.11.5
2020-10-27T17:46:36.985Z|00008|dpdk|INFO|DPDK Enabled - initializing...
2020-10-27T17:46:36.985Z|00009|dpdk|INFO|No vhost-sock-dir provided - defaulting to /usr/local/var/run/openvswitch
2020-10-27T17:46:36.985Z|00010|dpdk|INFO|IOMMU support for vhost-user-client disabled.
2020-10-27T17:46:36.985Z|00011|dpdk|INFO|POSTCOPY support for vhost-user-client disabled.
2020-10-27T17:46:36.985Z|00012|dpdk|INFO|Per port memory for DPDK devices disabled.
2020-10-27T17:46:36.985Z|00013|dpdk|INFO|EAL ARGS: ovs-vswitchd -c 0x6 --socket-mem 1024,1024 --socket-limit 1024,1024.
2020-10-27T17:46:36.988Z|00014|dpdk|INFO|EAL: Detected 24 lcore(s)
2020-10-27T17:46:36.988Z|00015|dpdk|INFO|EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
2020-10-27T17:46:37.026Z|00016|dpdk|INFO|EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
2020-10-27T17:46:37.042Z|00017|dpdk|INFO|EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
2020-10-27T17:46:37.051Z|00018|dpdk|WARN|EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
2020-10-27T17:46:37.051Z|00019|dpdk|WARN|EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
2020-10-27T17:46:37.051Z|00020|dpdk|WARN|EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
2020-10-27T17:46:37.051Z|00021|dpdk|INFO|EAL: Probing VFIO support...
2020-10-27T17:46:37.051Z|00022|dpdk|INFO|EAL: VFIO support initialized
2020-10-27T17:46:37.930Z|00023|dpdk|INFO|EAL: PCI device 0000:01:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
2020-10-27T17:46:37.930Z|00024|dpdk|INFO|EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1528 net_ixgbe
2020-10-27T17:46:37.930Z|00025|dpdk|INFO|EAL: PCI device 0000:01:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
2020-10-27T17:46:37.930Z|00026|dpdk|INFO|EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1528 net_ixgbe
2020-10-27T17:46:37.930Z|00027|dpdk|INFO|EAL: PCI device 0000:07:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
2020-10-27T17:46:37.930Z|00028|dpdk|INFO|EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
2020-10-27T17:46:37.995Z|00029|dpdk|INFO|EAL: PCI device 0000:07:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
2020-10-27T17:46:37.996Z|00030|dpdk|INFO|EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
2020-10-27T17:46:38.067Z|00031|dpdk|INFO|DPDK Enabled - initialized
2020-10-27T17:46:38.071Z|00032|pmd_perf|INFO|DPDK provided TSC frequency: 2600000 KHz
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00033|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports recirculation
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00034|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: VLAN header stack length probed as 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00035|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: MPLS label stack length probed as 3
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00036|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports truncate action
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00037|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports unique flow ids
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00038|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports clone action
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00039|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Max sample nesting level probed as 10
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00040|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports eventmask in conntrack action
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00041|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports ct_clear action
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00042|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Max dp_hash algorithm probed to be 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00043|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports check_pkt_len action
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00044|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports timeout policy in conntrack action
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00045|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports ct_state
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00046|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports ct_zone
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00047|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports ct_mark
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00048|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports ct_label
2020-10-27T17:46:38.083Z|00049|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports ct_state_nat
2020-10-27T17:46:38.084Z|00050|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports ct_orig_tuple
2020-10-27T17:46:38.084Z|00051|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports ct_orig_tuple6
2020-10-27T17:46:38.084Z|00052|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports IPv6 ND Extensions
2020-10-27T17:46:38.090Z|00053|bridge|INFO|bridge br0: added interface br0 on port 65534
2020-10-27T17:46:38.090Z|00054|netdev_dpdk|WARN|Failed to enable flow control on device 0
2020-10-27T17:46:38.099Z|00055|dpif_netdev|INFO|PMD thread on numa_id: 1, core id:  5 created.
2020-10-27T17:46:38.107Z|00056|dpif_netdev|INFO|PMD thread on numa_id: 0, core id:  2 created.
2020-10-27T17:46:38.107Z|00057|dpif_netdev|INFO|There are 1 pmd threads on numa node 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.107Z|00058|dpif_netdev|INFO|There are 1 pmd threads on numa node 0
2020-10-27T17:46:38.107Z|00059|dpdk|INFO|Device with port_id=0 already stopped
2020-10-27T17:46:38.382Z|00060|netdev_dpdk|INFO|Port 0: ec:f4:bb:e2:f4:94
2020-10-27T17:46:38.382Z|00061|dpif_netdev|INFO|Core 2 on numa node 0 assigned port 'dpdk-p0' rx queue 0 (measured processing cycles 0).
2020-10-27T17:46:38.383Z|00062|bridge|INFO|bridge br0: added interface dpdk-p0 on port 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.385Z|00063|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: Linear buffers requested without external buffers, disabling host segmentation offloading support
2020-10-27T17:46:38.390Z|00064|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: vhost-user client: socket created, fd: 1091
2020-10-27T17:46:38.390Z|00065|netdev_dpdk|INFO|vHost User device 'vhost-vm-2004-tpl' created in 'client' mode, using client socket '/var/run/openvswitch-vhost/vhost-vm-2004-tpl'
2020-10-27T17:46:38.394Z|00066|dpdk|WARN|VHOST_CONFIG: failed to connect to /var/run/openvswitch-vhost/vhost-vm-2004-tpl: No such file or directory
2020-10-27T17:46:38.394Z|00067|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: /var/run/openvswitch-vhost/vhost-vm-2004-tpl: reconnecting...
2020-10-27T17:46:38.538Z|00068|dpif_netdev|INFO|Core 2 on numa node 0 assigned port 'dpdk-p0' rx queue 0 (measured processing cycles 0).
2020-10-27T17:46:38.538Z|00069|dpif_netdev|INFO|Core 5 on numa node 1 assigned port 'vhost-vm-2004-tpl' rx queue 0 (measured processing cycles 0).
2020-10-27T17:46:38.538Z|00070|bridge|INFO|bridge br0: added interface vhost-vm-2004-tpl on port 2
2020-10-27T17:46:38.538Z|00071|bridge|INFO|bridge br0: using datapath ID 0000ecf4bbe2f494
2020-10-27T17:46:38.539Z|00072|connmgr|INFO|br0: added service controller "punix:/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/br0.mgmt"
2020-10-27T17:46:38.539Z|00073|timeval|WARN|Unreasonably long 1554ms poll interval (361ms user, 789ms system)
2020-10-27T17:46:38.539Z|00074|timeval|WARN|faults: 36263 minor, 0 major
2020-10-27T17:46:38.539Z|00075|timeval|WARN|disk: 0 reads, 24 writes
2020-10-27T17:46:38.539Z|00076|timeval|WARN|context switches: 857 voluntary, 1425 involuntary
2020-10-27T17:46:38.539Z|00077|coverage|INFO|Event coverage, avg rate over last: 5 seconds, last minute, last hour,  hash=072f9aca:
2020-10-27T17:46:38.539Z|00078|coverage|INFO|bridge_reconfigure         0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00079|coverage|INFO|ofproto_flush              0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00080|coverage|INFO|ofproto_update_port        0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 3
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00081|coverage|INFO|rev_flow_table             0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00082|coverage|INFO|cmap_expand                0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 44
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00083|coverage|INFO|cmap_shrink                0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 25
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00084|coverage|INFO|datapath_drop_upcall_error   0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 2
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00085|coverage|INFO|dpif_port_add              0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 3
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00086|coverage|INFO|dpif_flow_flush            0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00087|coverage|INFO|dpif_flow_get              0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 23
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00088|coverage|INFO|dpif_flow_put              0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 24
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00089|coverage|INFO|dpif_flow_del              0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 23
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00090|coverage|INFO|dpif_execute               0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 6
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00091|coverage|INFO|flow_extract               0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 4
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00092|coverage|INFO|miniflow_malloc            0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 35
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00093|coverage|INFO|hmap_pathological          0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 4
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00094|coverage|INFO|hmap_expand                0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 492
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00095|coverage|INFO|hmap_shrink                0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 2
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00096|coverage|INFO|netdev_received            0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00097|coverage|INFO|netdev_get_stats           0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 3
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00098|coverage|INFO|poll_create_node           0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 30
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00099|coverage|INFO|poll_zero_timeout          0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00100|coverage|INFO|seq_change                 0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 137
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00101|coverage|INFO|pstream_open               0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 3
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00102|coverage|INFO|stream_open                0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00103|coverage|INFO|util_xalloc                0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 9631
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00104|coverage|INFO|netdev_set_policing        0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 1
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00105|coverage|INFO|netdev_get_ethtool         0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 2
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00106|coverage|INFO|netlink_received           0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 87
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00107|coverage|INFO|netlink_recv_jumbo         0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 19
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00108|coverage|INFO|netlink_sent               0.0/sec     0.000/sec        0.0000/sec   total: 85
2020-10-27T17:46:38.540Z|00109|coverage|INFO|111 events never hit
2020-10-27T17:46:38.546Z|00110|netdev_dpdk|WARN|Failed to enable flow control on device 0
2020-10-27T17:46:38.547Z|00111|bridge|INFO|ovs-vswitchd (Open vSwitch) 2.14.90
2020-10-27T17:46:47.093Z|00112|memory|INFO|196052 kB peak resident set size after 10.1 seconds
2020-10-27T17:46:47.093Z|00113|memory|INFO|handlers:1 ports:3 revalidators:1 rules:5 udpif keys:2
2020-10-27T17:46:58.392Z|00001|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: /var/run/openvswitch-vhost/vhost-vm-2004-tpl: connected
2020-10-27T17:46:58.392Z|00002|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: new device, handle is 0
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00001|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_GET_FEATURES
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00002|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_GET_PROTOCOL_FEATURES
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00003|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_PROTOCOL_FEATURES
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00004|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: negotiated Vhost-user protocol features: 0xcb7
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00005|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_GET_QUEUE_NUM
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00006|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_SLAVE_REQ_FD
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00007|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_OWNER
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00008|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_GET_FEATURES
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00009|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_VRING_CALL
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00010|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: vring call idx:0 file:1100
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00011|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_VRING_CALL
2020-10-27T17:46:58.396Z|00012|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: vring call idx:1 file:1101
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00013|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_VRING_ENABLE
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00014|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: set queue enable: 1 to qp idx: 0
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00015|netdev_dpdk|INFO|State of queue 0 ( tx_qid 0 ) of vhost device '/var/run/openvswitch-vhost/vhost-vm-2004-tpl' changed to 'enabled'
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00016|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_VRING_ENABLE
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00017|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: set queue enable: 1 to qp idx: 1
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00018|netdev_dpdk|INFO|State of queue 1 ( rx_qid 0 ) of vhost device '/var/run/openvswitch-vhost/vhost-vm-2004-tpl' changed to 'enabled'
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00019|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_VRING_ENABLE
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00020|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: set queue enable: 1 to qp idx: 0
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00021|netdev_dpdk|INFO|State of queue 0 ( tx_qid 0 ) of vhost device '/var/run/openvswitch-vhost/vhost-vm-2004-tpl' changed to 'enabled'
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00022|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_VRING_ENABLE
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00023|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: set queue enable: 1 to qp idx: 1
2020-10-27T17:47:01.905Z|00024|netdev_dpdk|INFO|State of queue 1 ( rx_qid 0 ) of vhost device '/var/run/openvswitch-vhost/vhost-vm-2004-tpl' changed to 'enabled'
2020-10-27T17:47:01.908Z|00025|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_FEATURES
2020-10-27T17:47:01.908Z|00026|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: negotiated Virtio features: 0x17020a782
2020-10-27T17:47:50.172Z|00001|dpif_netdev(revalidator6)|ERR|internal error parsing flow key skb_priority(0),skb_mark(0),ct_state(0),ct_zone(0),ct_mark(0),ct_label(0),recirc_id(0),dp_hash(0),in_port(2),packet_type(ns=0,id=0),eth(src=54:b2:03:14:d0:39,dst=01:00:5e:00:00:01),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=0.0.0.0,dst=224.0.0.1,proto=2,tos=0xc0,ttl=1,frag=no)
2020-10-27T17:47:50.172Z|00002|dpif(revalidator6)|WARN|netdev@ovs-netdev: failed to put[modify] (Invalid argument) ufid:94f25b77-62c5-4859-aec3-e9a41c72dc3d skb_priority(0/0),skb_mark(0/0),ct_state(0/0),ct_zone(0/0),ct_mark(0/0),ct_label(0/0),recirc_id(0),dp_hash(0/0),in_port(2),packet_type(ns=0,id=0),eth(src=54:b2:03:14:d0:39,dst=01:00:5e:00:00:01),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,dst=224.0.0.1/0.0.0.0,proto=2/0,tos=0xc0/0,ttl=1/0,frag=no), actions:userspace(pid=0,slow_path(match))
2020-10-27T17:47:52.680Z|00003|dpif_netdev(revalidator6)|ERR|internal error parsing flow key skb_priority(0),skb_mark(0),ct_state(0),ct_zone(0),ct_mark(0),ct_label(0),recirc_id(0),dp_hash(0),in_port(2),packet_type(ns=0,id=0),eth(src=44:2c:05:ce:8d:03,dst=01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=192.168.27.150,dst=239.255.255.250,proto=2,tos=0xc0,ttl=1,frag=no)
2020-10-27T17:47:52.680Z|00004|dpif(revalidator6)|WARN|netdev@ovs-netdev: failed to put[modify] (Invalid argument) ufid:aff312f9-4416-49e4-a314-9f895aa96de1 skb_priority(0/0),skb_mark(0/0),ct_state(0/0),ct_zone(0/0),ct_mark(0/0),ct_label(0/0),recirc_id(0),dp_hash(0/0),in_port(2),packet_type(ns=0,id=0),eth(src=44:2c:05:ce:8d:03,dst=01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=192.168.27.150/0.0.0.0,dst=239.255.255.250/0.0.0.0,proto=2/0,tos=0xc0/0,ttl=1/0,frag=no), actions:userspace(pid=0,slow_path(match))
2020-10-27T17:47:55.009Z|00005|dpif_netdev(revalidator6)|ERR|internal error parsing flow key skb_priority(0),skb_mark(0),ct_state(0),ct_zone(0),ct_mark(0),ct_label(0),recirc_id(0),dp_hash(0),in_port(2),packet_type(ns=0,id=0),eth(src=00:02:c9:50:8a:f0,dst=01:00:5e:00:00:fb),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=192.168.27.232,dst=224.0.0.251,proto=2,tos=0,ttl=1,frag=no)
2020-10-27T17:47:55.009Z|00006|dpif_netdev(revalidator6)|ERR|internal error parsing flow key skb_priority(0),skb_mark(0),ct_state(0),ct_zone(0),ct_mark(0),ct_label(0),recirc_id(0),dp_hash(0),in_port(2),packet_type(ns=0,id=0),eth(src=56:ed:b8:d2:f1:e3,dst=01:00:5e:00:00:6a),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=192.168.27.101,dst=224.0.0.106,proto=2,tos=0xc0,ttl=1,frag=no)
2020-10-27T17:47:55.009Z|00007|dpif(revalidator6)|WARN|netdev@ovs-netdev: failed to put[modify] (Invalid argument) ufid:b108050d-511e-447d-8837-35af4af81c4e skb_priority(0/0),skb_mark(0/0),ct_state(0/0),ct_zone(0/0),ct_mark(0/0),ct_label(0/0),recirc_id(0),dp_hash(0/0),in_port(2),packet_type(ns=0,id=0),eth(src=00:02:c9:50:8a:f0,dst=01:00:5e:00:00:fb),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=192.168.27.232/0.0.0.0,dst=224.0.0.251/0.0.0.0,proto=2/0,tos=0/0,ttl=1/0,frag=no), actions:userspace(pid=0,slow_path(match))
2020-10-27T17:47:55.009Z|00008|dpif(revalidator6)|WARN|netdev@ovs-netdev: failed to put[modify] (Invalid argument) ufid:02feab90-66a5-484c-bbc5-8e97985d1f73 skb_priority(0/0),skb_mark(0/0),ct_state(0/0),ct_zone(0/0),ct_mark(0/0),ct_label(0/0),recirc_id(0),dp_hash(0/0),in_port(2),packet_type(ns=0,id=0),eth(src=56:ed:b8:d2:f1:e3,dst=01:00:5e:00:00:6a),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=192.168.27.101/0.0.0.0,dst=224.0.0.106/0.0.0.0,proto=2/0,tos=0xc0/0,ttl=1/0,frag=no), actions:userspace(pid=0,slow_path(match))
2020-10-27T17:47:56.014Z|00009|dpif_netdev(revalidator6)|ERR|internal error parsing flow key skb_priority(0),skb_mark(0),ct_state(0),ct_zone(0),ct_mark(0),ct_label(0),recirc_id(0),dp_hash(0),in_port(2),packet_type(ns=0,id=0),eth(src=00:02:c9:50:8a:f0,dst=01:00:5e:00:00:fc),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=192.168.27.232,dst=224.0.0.252,proto=2,tos=0,ttl=1,frag=no)
2020-10-27T17:47:56.014Z|00010|dpif(revalidator6)|WARN|netdev@ovs-netdev: failed to put[modify] (Invalid argument) ufid:22a5115c-c730-42b2-a590-87b999192781 skb_priority(0/0),skb_mark(0/0),ct_state(0/0),ct_zone(0/0),ct_mark(0/0),ct_label(0/0),recirc_id(0),dp_hash(0/0),in_port(2),packet_type(ns=0,id=0),eth(src=00:02:c9:50:8a:f0,dst=01:00:5e:00:00:fc),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=192.168.27.232/0.0.0.0,dst=224.0.0.252/0.0.0.0,proto=2/0,tos=0/0,ttl=1/0,frag=no), actions:userspace(pid=0,slow_path(match))
```

Comment: assuming `your ovs dpdk port `dpdk-p0` is connected to switch which has access to DHCP. Since the GUEST os is running the server port it should run before the ovs`I. f these are true, port `vhost-vm-2004-t` for GUEST would get packets. But from `dump-ports` the link is down. So can you please try brining up the port in guest and host using `sudo`. then run `dhcpclient` for the port in VM. If link is not coming up in VM, please check dmesg for the cause of error.

Comment: the port "0000:07:00.0" has already connect to a network with DHCP, when i try to bring up the port by command " ip link set ens3 up" in vm by root , the error result is "RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted"

Comment: as asked since you are using server mode in VM, you should be running the VM first then ovs. I have already pointed out in the `dump-ports` is showing interface down.

Comment: 0000:07:00.0 is dpdk-p0 physical interface your issue lies on `vhost-vm-2004-tpl`. This Is connected as client mode, for this to work properly first you have to start the VM which is server mode, Then ovs switched has to be started. The logs call out `failed to connect to /var/run/openvswitch-vhost/vhost-vm-2004-tpl: No such file or directory`